# What is the standard or best way to deal with database branching with Mercurial or Git branches?

Tags: database, git, mercurial, branch

This has been a big question mark on my mind.

I'm moving to Mercurial or Git very soon for my web software, and sometimes my branches require significant database changes which other branches should not see. This, I can't always share the same database for my branches.

Is there some standard way of dealing with database changes for branching and cloning? What do you all do? I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

Using a database changset tool can be really helpful. I've used liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org), at work to manage version control for the db. I would warmly recommend that tool to anyone. Liquibase does support changesets, with configurable rollback scenarios. However, it is a tool for managing the schema, not the actual data. I wouldn't try to use it to keep the table data up-to-date.

However, I still feel that your best bet is to use liquibase, and have different schemas, for different source branches.

Comment: Was it easy to resolve merge conflicts in the changelog? Does it have a built-in solution for checkouts?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an answer for you, but I did come across a recent article that might be relevant: [Why your database version control strategy sucks and what to do about it, Part I](http://mooneyblog.mmdbsolutions.com/index.php/2010/03/23/why-your-database-version-control-strategy-sucks-and-what-to-do-about-it-part-i/)

Answer (score 2):

For handling cloning, your database should be designed to be multi-user.

For changes in schema, commit changes to the schema for that branch as part of the respository.

Then you have to make up your mind, for each schema, do you run multiple tablespaces in one database, multiple databases, etc.? Then commit a pointer to the correct one as part of the installation configuration in that branch.

Comment: What do you mean by a pointer? Are you talking about changing the DSN for each branch?

Comment: What do you mean by "designed to be multi-user?" Do you mean, if each developer has a branch, it should work for each of those branches?

Comment: A clone of the repo is just that, an identical clone, complete with internal branches. If the concern is handling cloning, then (I suppose) the concern is that multiple developers will access a database at once, or a single developer with multiple cloned repositories will access the database from more than one copy of the running application. For this instance alone, ignoring branches, if your databases are multi-user, handling cloned repositories is taken care of.

Comment: I used the vague term "pointer" because the nature of the pointer depends on the nature of your solution. If you are using multiple tablespaces in one database, they could all share the same DSN. If you are using multiple databases, you could switch between them using the DSN.

Answer (score 0):

The database schema is itself (recorded in) a database whose structure is, more or less, defined by the INFORMATION_SCHEMA of the SQL standard.

Now, DBMS's are designed quite deliberately to allow only one single database value at any one single point in time.  And since the catalog is itself "just a database value for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database", SQL systems support, quite deliberately, only one single database structure at any one single point in time.